# Add signature to Outlook mail VS2012

Tags: email, visual-studio-2012, outlook, signature, outlook-2007

I'm making a signature button that on click should add my signature on the bottom of the page. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and i've made the button, but since i don't understand this programming language i would need some help.

OnClick add my NewMessagesSignature to the bottom of the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Within `Outlook`, I am using the following `VBA` macro to add my signature to the mail which is currently in the edit window:

```
Public Sub addAxelSignature()
    ' Alt-H G Enter
    SendKeys "%hg~"
End Sub
```

So, the macro just emulates my manual sequence of buttons to add a signature. Not ideal, but it works.

You can implement all sorts of fancy `Outlook` extensions/add-ins using [Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office). But for adding a signature, a simple `VBA` macro would be sufficient.